# Infinitely Divisible Distributions and Maximal Entropy

Tags: probability-distributions, entropy

The normal distribution on $\mathbb{R}$, the exponential distribution on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, and the geometric distribution on $\mathbb{N}$ are examples of distributions that are both infinitely divisible and entropy maximizers.  On the other hand, the Poisson distribution is an infinitely divisible distribution on $\mathbb{N}$ without maximizing entropy, while the uniform distribution on the interval $[a,b]$ maximizes entropy but is not infinitely divisible.

Can anything be said about the relationship between these two classes of distributions?

Comment: I don't see a-priori why there should be some intrinsic relationship between infinite divisibility and max-ent, but maybe i am missing some intuition here.

Comment: Doesn't the Poisson distribution maximize entropy with respect to the measure that assigns $1/n!$ to $\{n\}$ for $n \in \{0,1,2,\ldots\}$, among all measures on $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ having a given expected value?  (BTW, a nice way to see istantly that the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ is not infinitely divisible is that its fourth cumulant is negative.  The even-degree cumulants of infinitely divisible distributions are non-negative.)

Comment: So I see I posted a remark 11 years ago, and now I think there is a mistake there. It is true that among compound Poisson distributions, the fourth cumulant is never negative, but now I think that is probably not true of infinitely divisible distributions generally.

Answer (score 5):

The Poisson distribution has maximum entropy under the condition of having a specific mean and being a sum of Bernoulli random variables. The condition of being a sum of Bernoulli random variables can be weakened to being ultra log-concave.

Comment: Is this still true if one considers sums of integer multiples of Bernoulli random variables?